# files names suffix "unknown"

Tags: 14.04, unity, filename

On my desktop all created file names include the suffix "unknown".
Please look at the screenshot:
[file name unknown](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=92897)
Almost funny bug...it appears since a few updates and exclusive on my desktop but not inside of the folders

thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, I can delete it and deleted file does not comes back. And yes, It is important for me. It looks just defective. We don't want to make Ubuntu looking defective :-)

Comment: excuseme, why did I get 1 point for unclear quastion? I don't understand. Why the one Helper became erased, who asked me for deleted files??

Comment: I was looking for more information: In each affected file properties is the VOLUME entry marked as "unknown".